# How to use the client side(JS) variable in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have the following JS code.

```
var thisItem = document.thisItem;
var e-mail = thisItem.getProperty("email");// which gets the e-mail of the User
```

And I have the following C# code.

```
public static void Main()
{
   string username = "username";
   string email = ""; 
   //code to send a mail to the user
}
```

In JS code I' m using applyMethod("CSProgramName"); to run the C# from client side. 
Here I want to use the Javascript 'e-mail' variable in C# code. How Can I do this?

Comment: `public static void Main()`... Is it a winforms/console application?

Comment: More context is needed as it is not clear how/where your run your javascript and how your app interacts with.

Comment: In my app I hav created an action(JS), Click on the action opens a dialog where we should select an user, the selected user' s e-mail ID gets stored in JS 'e-mail' variable and in the same JS code I' m calling applyMethod("C#prgName"); which runs C# code. Her at this point I want to use the JS 'e-mail' variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Have some hidden text box and assign the value through javascript and access the control.

If it is ASP.Net I would suggest to use ajax post to your C# code like below.

```
var reqUrl = "http://mysite/Sample/Sample.aspx?post=true";
var jqXHRresponse;
var request = $.ajax({
                 url: reqUrl,
                 type: "POST",
                 data: {email:emailAddress},
                 dataType: 'json'
 }); 


protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.Params["post"] == "true")
  {
    string email = Request.Params["email"];
  }
}
```